# How to code a script that outputs a separate value every time a certain number is reached

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have a table that looks similar to this:

```
Time                     degF
10/2/2019 8:20:50        78
10/2/2019 8:21:00        100
10/2/2019 8:21:10        160
10/2/2019 8:21:20        210
10/2/2019 8:21:30        300
10/2/2019 8:21:40        250
10/2/2019 8:21:50        220
10/2/2019 8:22:00        185
10/2/2019 8:22:10        120
```

In which the temperature data repeats in this oscillating curve manner for an extended period of time. I am trying to write a code that determines the time output each time the temperatures passes 200 and then categorize them separately. For example, in this case I would take the first time 200 is passed (8:21:20) and then the second time (8:22:00) and store each one individually (e.g. time1 and time2).

I currently am importing this data from a csv file and converting the values using to_datetime and to_numeric.

My current code looks like this:

```
for i,t in zip (CH1,DT):
    if i == 160:
        print(t)
        trial1 = t

for i,t in zip (CH1,DT):
    if i == 185:
        print(t)
        trial2 = t
```

Where CH1 is the temperature variable and DT is the time variable.

While this code prints out the proper time associated with the temperature value I need, it only does so for one specific temperature and I'm not sure how to iterate code that says 'once it hits' 200 and then store each time the data goes past 200 as its own output.

Comment: Have you tried `if i >= 200:` ?

Comment: Would that not out every value over 200? I need the time where 200 is 'hit' so to speak.

Comment: Only to output something when the value is equal to 200?